# Incompatible Shape Error [32, 150,150,3] vs [32] for an Autoencoder

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, autoencoder

Please Help, I am trying to make an Autoencoder from a dataset of 533,248 images but I can't seem to get the shape right when I go to fit my model. The code I have is below.

```
SRC_DIR = r"/tmp/Dataset"
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HGT = 150
IMG_WID = 150
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

x_train = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
   SRC_DIR,
   validation_split=0.199952,
   subset="training",
   seed = 123,
   shuffle = False,
   image_size=(IMG_HGT, IMG_WID),
   batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
   )

x_test = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
   SRC_DIR,
   validation_split=0.199952,
   subset="validation",
   seed = 123,
   shuffle = False,
   image_size=(IMG_HGT, IMG_WID),
   batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
   )

class_names = x_train.class_names
print(class_names)

x_train = x_train.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
x_test = x_test.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

print(x_train)
print(x_test)

latent_dim = 64

class Autoencoder(Model):

   def __init__(self,latent_dim):
       super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
       self.latent_dim=latent_dim
       self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
           layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape = (IMG_HGT, IMG_WID,3)),
           layers.Flatten(), 
           layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
           ])
       self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
           layers.Dense(IMG_HGT * IMG_WID * 3, activation = 'sigmoid'), 
           layers.Reshape((IMG_HGT, IMG_WID,3))
           ])

   def call(self,x):
       encoded = self.encoder(x)
       decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
       return decoded


autoencoder= Autoencoder(latent_dim)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = losses.MeanSquaredError())
autoencoder.fit(x_train,
                epochs = 1, 
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                shuffle=False, 
                validation_data=x_test)
```

The output of my code is below:

```
Found 533248 files belonging to 3 classes.
Using 426624 files for training.
Found 533248 files belonging to 3 classes.
Using 106624 files for validation.
['AD', 'MCI', 'NL']
<_PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), dtype=tf.float32, 
name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
<_PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 150, 150, 3), dtype=tf.float32, 
name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None))>
```

The received Error is below:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-66b9b917f59a> in <cell line: 85>()
    83 autoencoder= Autoencoder(latent_dim)
    84 autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = losses.MeanSquaredError())
---> 85 autoencoder.fit(x_train,
    86                 epochs = 1,
    87                 batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in 
quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
    50   try:
    51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
    53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
    54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at 
(most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in 
<module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 
992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in 
start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 215, 
in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 687, in 
<lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 740, in 
_run_callback
     ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 821, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 782, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in 
process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in 
dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in 
execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in 
do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in 
 run_cell
   return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 
 2975, in run_cell
  result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 
 3030, in _run_cell
     return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 
 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
    coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 
 3257, in run_cell_async
     has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 
 3473, in run_ast_nodes
  if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 
 3553, in run_code
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-1-66b9b917f59a>", line 85, in <cell line: 85>
  autoencoder.fit(x_train,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
  return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
  tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
  return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
  outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
  outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1054, in train_step
  self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 542, in minimize
  grads_and_vars = self.compute_gradients(loss, var_list, tape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 275, in compute_gradients
  grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list)
Node: 'gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs'
Incompatible shapes: [32,150,150,3] vs. [32]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] 
[Op:__inference_train_function_843]
```

I'm very confused because I double checked the input shapes from x_train and x_test and they're both [none,150,150,3] so I don't know why the shapes are not compatible since I can't tell the model.fit the expected input shape. Thanks ahead of time!!!